# sympy matrix.factor() fails with message about 'noncommutative scalars'

Tags: python, sympy

I am looking for how to extract common factors of sympy symbolic matrices.

A minimal example would be:

```py
import sympy as sy

N = sy.Symbol("N", integer=True, positive=True)
P = sy.Symbol("P", integer=True, positive=True)
X = sy.MatrixSymbol("X", N, P)
Y = sy.MatrixSymbol("Y", N, P)

example =  X * X.T + Y * X.T

example.factor()
```

Fails with

```
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sympy/matrices/expressions/matmul.py in as_coeff_matrices(self)
    132         coeff = Mul(*scalars)
    133         if coeff.is_commutative is False:
--> 134             raise NotImplementedError("noncommutative scalars in MatMul are not supported.")
    135 
    136         return coeff, matrices

NotImplementedError: noncommutative scalars in MatMul are not supported.
```

Where I was expecting something like:

`(X + Y) * X.T`

Anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: `factor_nc` in `sympy.matrices.expressions.factors` module?

Comment: Are you sure you can actually use a symbol as a matrix dimension? (EDIT: after scrolling down further in the docs, looks like some of the examples under "Block Matrices" use symbolic dimensions, so apparently that's supported.)

Comment: This is a bug. Please report to github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues